# KendoUI Angular Grid external command

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

i'm using KendoUI-Grid in an Angular (5) app.

html:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="GRIDData"            
  (add)="addHandler($event)">
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <button kendoGridAddCommand type="button">Add new</button>
  </ng-template>
```

component:

```
public addHandler({sender}) {
  this.formGroup = createFormGroup({
    'Id': 'NEW',
    'Name': 'New entry'
  });
sender.addRow(this.formGroup);
}
```

**Is it possible to trigger the addCommand (or any other) from outside the grid?**
Perhaps something like:

html:

```
<button (click)="gridAddRow()"> Add New Row to Grid</button>
```

comnponent:

```
gridAddRow() {
  **//calling addHandler ({sender})**
}
```

**THX**

Answer (score 1):

Yup! the grid is a component. You just need a reference to it.

HTML:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="GRIDData"            
  (add)="addHandler($event)">
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <button kendoGridAddCommand type="button">Add new</button>
</ng-template>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild(GridComponent) private grid: GridComponent;

gridAddRow() {
  **//calling addHandler ({sender})**
  this.grid.addRow(** your form group goes here **)
}
```

stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruohgs

Comment: WORKS GREAT
THANKS

Comment: @Ringo, Can you please provide an example of this ? As i am not able to achieve with this code.

Comment: @RohitJindal here ya go :) 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruohgs