# Execute [kendoGridAddCommand] on component init

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular5, kendo-angular-ui

**[Kendo Default Behaviour](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-reactive-forms/)**

The `add` event fires when the `kendoGridAddCommand` under `kendoGridToolbarTemplate` is clicked.

**HTML :**

```
<kendo-grid 
(add)="addHandler($event)"
>
    <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
        <button kendoGridAddCommand>Add new</button>
    </ng-template>
    <kendo-grid-column field="id" title="ID" width="120"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="name" width="120"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

**TS :**

```
protected addHandler({sender}) {
    // define all editable fields validators and default values
    const group = new FormGroup({
        'id': new FormControl(),
        'name': new FormControl()
    });

    // show the new row editor, with the `FormGroup` build above
    sender.addRow(group);
}
```

**Requirement**

Trigger the [addrow](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-addrow) event on component init or outside the Grid. By default one row should display with the form controls without click on `Add new` button.

I tried the below solution provided in SO but did not get success.

[KendoUI Angular Grid external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48303995/kendoui-angular-grid-external-command/48304660)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the AfterViewInit event, and call the Grid [addRow method](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-addrow), e.g.:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
        'ProductID': new FormControl(),
        'ProductName': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'UnitPrice': new FormControl(0),
        'UnitsInStock': new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1,3}')])),
        'Discontinued': new FormControl(false)
  });

  this.grid.addRow(this.formGroup);
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5rc6g?file=app/app.component.ts)